# Can I reactivate a chemoluminescent reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, photochemistry

I have created a firefly jar with glow sticks to sell at a school fair. The firefly jar lasts only for an hour or so. I have heard that glow sticks can be reactivated. The firefly jars contain the chemicals found in good sticks. Is there any way to make the jar glow again?

Comment: Nope sorry I'm looking for a way to recharge a firefly jar, not glow stick

Comment: If firefly jars contain the same chemicals as a glow stick, then the answer to a question about recharging glowsticks (it's possible but challenging) answers this question also. In short, you need to add more peroxide and more oxalate ester. Or you could shine a black light on it.

Comment: Any tips on how to recharge? My jars contain much less chemical than a glow stick because glow sticks are jammed pack but my jars only have a small volume of the chemical

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, you can't!

Longer answer: Still no, and this is why: The reaction between the oxalate and hydrogen peroxide is **irreversible**. Both compounds are consumed in the reaction and there is no way back!

The only compound that survives is a fluorescent material, that absorbs in the UV, emits in the visible range and gives the colour that you finally observe.

As **Ben Norris** pointed out in his comment, your only options are:

- add fresh diphenyloxalate and hydrogen peroxide (which again will be consumed) or
- irradiate the fluorescent compound that has survived with a UV lamp

Comment: OK the. Do any of the suggested methods on the internet work then ( freezer, boiling water).?

Comment: @user3889649 No, when it's gone it's gone. You might be able to slow down the reaction in a freezer, but once mixed, hydrogen peroxide and diphenyloxalate will not unmix. Instead, they will  react  and the reaction will not stop until the starting materials are consumed.